# First Monday of Current Month in VBA

Tags: vba, ms-access

Using VBA is it possible to get the first Monday of the current month? I had thought the below would work :-

```
DateSerial(Year(Date), Month(Date), ((7 - Weekday(DateSerial(Year(Date), Month(Date), 7))) + 2) Mod 7)
```

...but if I use this today for example, I get a date of 31/07/2017, which obviously is last month.

Comment: Your title is really perfect, why don't you google it?

Comment: @Vityata If could find the answer doing that, I wouldn't be posting here...

Comment: No problem, I have done the googling for you :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Edit:
This is a possible answer ([so the first one in google is a false one](https://www.google.com/search?q=First%20Monday%20of%20Current%20Month%20in%20VBA&oq=First%20Monday%20of%20Current%20Month%20in%20VBA&aqs=chrome..69i57j69i60l2j69i61.247j0j7&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8)) :

```
Public Function FirstMonday(myDate As Date) As Date

    Dim d As Date, w As Long
    d = DateSerial(Year(myDate), month(myDate), 1)
    w = Weekday(d, vbMonday)
    FirstMonday = d + IIf(w <> 1, 8 - w, 0)

End Function
```

This is how you call it:

```
Public Sub Test
   debug.print FirstMonday(Now)
End sub
```

In general, here is an interesting reading for [Excel Date Functions](http://www.cpearson.com/excel/DateFunctions1.aspx).

Comment: This post is correct, but the last line needs to be: `FirstMonday = d + IIf(w = 1, 0, 8 - w)`

Comment: @FloLie - yup, `vbSunday` was not brining any info.

Comment: @Vityata Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You can use this generic function:

```
' Calculates the date of the occurrence of Weekday in the month of DateInMonth.
'
' If Occurrence is 0 or negative, the first occurrence of Weekday in the month is assumed.
' If Occurrence is 5 or larger, the last occurrence of Weekday in the month is assumed.
'
' If Weekday is invalid or not specified, the weekday of DateInMonth is used.
'
' 2016-06-09. Gustav Brock, Cactus Data ApS, CPH.
'
Public Function DateWeekdayInMonth( _
    ByVal DateInMonth As Date, _
    Optional ByVal Occurrence As Integer, _
    Optional ByVal Weekday As VbDayOfWeek = -1) _
    As Date

    Const DaysInWeek    As Integer = 7

    Dim Offset          As Integer
    Dim Month           As Integer
    Dim Year            As Integer
    Dim ResultDate      As Date

    ' Validate Weekday.
    Select Case Weekday
        Case _
            vbMonday, _
            vbTuesday, _
            vbWednesday, _
            vbThursday, _
            vbFriday, _
            vbSaturday, _
            vbSunday
        Case Else
            ' Zero, none or invalid value for VbDayOfWeek.
            Weekday = VBA.Weekday(DateInMonth)
    End Select

    ' Validate Occurence.
    If Occurrence <= 0 Then
        Occurrence = 1
    ElseIf Occurrence > 5 Then
        Occurrence = 5
    End If

    ' Start date.
    Month = VBA.Month(DateInMonth)
    Year = VBA.Year(DateInMonth)
    ResultDate = DateSerial(Year, Month, 1)

    ' Find offset of Weekday from first day of month.
    Offset = DaysInWeek * (Occurrence - 1) + (Weekday - VBA.Weekday(ResultDate) + DaysInWeek) Mod DaysInWeek
    ' Calculate result date.
    ResultDate = DateAdd("d", Offset, ResultDate)

    If Occurrence = 5 Then
        ' The latest occurrency of Weekday is requested.
        ' Check if there really is a fifth occurrence of Weekday in this month.
        If VBA.Month(ResultDate) <> Month Then
            ' There are only four occurrencies of Weekday in this month.
            ' Return the fourth as the latest.
            ResultDate = DateAdd("d", -DaysInWeek, ResultDate)
        End If
    End If

    DateWeekdayInMonth = ResultDate

End Function
```

Then:

```
FirstMonday = DateWeekdayInMonth(Date, 1, vbMonday)
```

Answer (score 0):

Run the following macro and it gives you the first Monday of the Month:

```
Sub PromptFirstMondayofTheCurrentMonth()

Dim a As Variant

a = Date - Day(Date) + 1

MsgBox IIf(Weekday(a, vbMonday) = 1, 1, 9 - Weekday(a, vbMonday))

End Sub
```