# Find first Monday of given month or last Monday of previous month

Tags: vba, date, weekday

If the first day of the month is Monday to Wednesday the first Monday is that current week.

If the first day is Thursday to Sunday the first Monday is the following Monday.

Examples:

August 2021 - the first Monday would be 02/08/2021 as the first day of the month is Sunday (i.e. after Wednesday).

September 2021 - the first Monday would be 30/08/2021 as the first day of the month is Wednesday.

October 2021 - the first Monday would be 04/10/2021 as the first day of the month is a Friday.

The following code gives the first Monday of the month.

```vb
Public Function FirstMonday(myDate As Date) As Date
    Dim d As Date, w As Long
    d = DateSerial(Year(myDate), month(myDate), 1)
    w = Weekday(d, vbMonday)
    FirstMonday = d + IIf(w <> 1, 8 - w, 0)
End Function
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [First Monday of Current Month in VBA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45564927/first-monday-of-current-month-in-vba)

Comment: You can use the generic function `DateWeekdayInMonthFirst` in module `DateFind` found at [VBA.Date](https://github.com/GustavBrock/VBA.Date).

Comment: dim myFirstMonday as date --> Dim myFirstWednesday as date -->   myDate =  FirstMonday("01/10/2021") --> myFirstWednesday = dateAdd("d", 2, myFirstMonday)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You were close. For your test dates, this gave me the expected response:

```
Public Function FirstMonday(myDate As Date) As Date
   Dim d As Date, w As Long
   d = DateSerial(Year(myDate), Month(myDate), 1)
   w = Weekday(d, vbMonday)

   If w > 3 Then
       FirstMonday = d + (8 - w)
   Else
       FirstMonday = d - w + 1
   End If

End Function
```

When `w > 3`, the first day of a month is Thursday to Sunday. In that case, add the days missing to the following Monday (`8 - w`). Else, go backwards and substract `w - 1` to get to the previous week's Monday.

Answer (score 1):

To break down your question, what you really are looking for is *the Monday before the first Wednesday of the month*.

So, just find the first wednesday then subtract two days!! No over-complicating things with `If ... Else`  statements needed.

```
Public Function FirstMonday(myDate As Date) As Date
    Dim d As Date, w As Long
    d = DateSerial(Year(myDate), Month(myDate), 1)

    w = Weekday(d, vbThursday)  'Thursday = 1, Friday = 2, Wednesday = 7
    d = d + 7 - w               'Adjusts d from being first day to first wednesday

    FirstMonday = d - 2         'The Monday before
End Function
```

Answer (score 0):

Give this version a try:

```
Public Function FirstMonday(myDate As Date) As Date
   Dim d As Date, w As Long
   d = DateSerial(Year(myDate), Month(myDate), 1)
   w = Weekday(d, vbMonday)
   If w >= 1 And w <= 3 Then d = d - 7
   FirstMonday = d + 8 - w
End Function
```

`d` will hold the date of the first day of month
`w` will get the day of week for this date (Monday=1, Sunday=7)
When the day of week is Monday to Wednesday (`w` is 1..3), we go back one week (`d = d - 7`).
With that date, we calculate the next Monday (`d + 8 - w`).

This is the result:

| Month | First of Month | First Monday |
| --- | --- | --- |
| January | Friday, January 01, 2021 | Monday, January 04, 2021 |
| February | Monday, February 01, 2021 | Monday, February 01, 2021 |
| March | Monday, March 01, 2021 | Monday, March 01, 2021 |
| April | Thursday, April 01, 2021 | Monday, April 05, 2021 |
| May | Saturday, May 01, 2021 | Monday, May 03, 2021 |
| June | Tuesday, June 01, 2021 | Monday, May 31, 2021 |
| July | Thursday, July 01, 2021 | Monday, July 05, 2021 |
| August | Sunday, August 01, 2021 | Monday, August 02, 2021 |
| September | Wednesday, September 01, 2021 | Monday, August 30, 2021 |
| October | Friday, October 01, 2021 | Monday, October 04, 2021 |
| November | Monday, November 01, 2021 | Monday, November 01, 2021 |
| December | Wednesday, December 01, 2021 | Monday, November 29, 2021 |

Answer (score 0):

I didn't find that the last example worked for all dates.   Here is an adjusted version that will work for all dates:

```
Public Function FirstMonday(myDate As Date)
Dim d As Date, w As Long
    d = DateSerial(Year(myDate), Month(myDate), 1)
    w = Weekday(d) ' Monday = 2
    Do Until w = 2
        d = d + 1
        w = Weekday(d)
    Loop
    ' now have first Monday for d
    FirstMonday = d
End Function
```